# How write a one-sentence arabic text in a latin document?

Tags: arabic

Is it possible to write one line with arabic letter in a latin-alphabet document?

something like

```
...
How are you...
سۆمتینگ سۆمتینگ...
now the latin is continued here
...
```

How about mixing with equation and so on? 
Please notice that I use tons of packages for writing maths and drawing Feynman-diagrams and the like.

I have arabic/english keyboard.

Answer (score 4):

run with `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Script=Arabic]{DejaVu Sans}
\usepackage{arabluatex}
\begin{document}
    La scrittura araba ha la sua origine nello script Byblos e lo script fenicio. La forma delle 
    lettere e le basi per l'ulteriore sviluppo della scrittura sono stati collocati nello script 
    aramaico.
\begin{txarab}  
    الكتابة العربية وأصله في البرنامج النصي بيبلوس الفينيقية والنصي. وضعت على شكل الحروف والأسس لمزيد 


    من التنمية في الكتابة الآرامية النصي.
\end{txarab}
    La scrittura araba ha la sua origine nello script Byblos e lo script fenicio. La forma delle 
    lettere e le basi per l'ulteriore sviluppo della scrittura sono stati collocati nello script 
    aramaico.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: xelatex and lulatex doesn't seem to work for me since I have all kinds of packages and stuff, there seems to be some kind of conflict. I don't know how to copy the error codes unfortunately.

Comment: The only difference is the font loading and `utf8` id the default input encoding. That's all ...

Comment: You still need to mark the whole Arabic paragraph right to left since the order of the words is still left to right in XeTeX (in LuaTeX it is even worse, as even the individual letters inside the words will be from left to right).

Comment: @KhaledHosny Assalamu Alaykom :) If I need to type some enumeration list with Arabic text inside an English document, is it possible to do so using pdflatex? Or do I have to switch to lualatex or xelatex?

Comment: @Diaa: I’m not the best one to answer such questions, and this is a new question not a comment, so please consider asking a new question.

Comment: @user2478 How to write a word in text arab, in the same row with latin?

Comment: @user 2478: Reading the manual just find:  \arb{المأمون} is the way to insert arab text in a row.