# Adding Arabic text to English document

Tags: languages, arabic, arabxetex

I'm trying to include Arabic text in an English document (I'm a new latex user), but I can't seem to get any Arabic text to render at all, using xelatex or any kind of tex. I'm using texshop 3.51 on a mac. I can't get this basic example to work, it just displays question marks in the output pdf.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf]{arabxetex}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
\begin{document}
\begin{arab}[voc]
وَهَذِهِ فِقرَةٌ بِالعَرَبِيَة مَعَ كَلِمَة اِنكلِيزِيَة
\end{arab}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I've downloaded Amiri (and also Scheherazade and Lateef) into Fontbook, and they show up if I go Source->Font->Show Fonts in texshop. If I remove the Amiri part it still doesn't work.

Is there anything I can do? I've looked at other links here, like [Arabic text with Polyglossia](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159903/arabic-text-with-polyglossia) and [How write a one-sentence arabic text in a latin document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175045/how-write-a-one-sentence-arabic-text-in-a-latin-document) but I can't even render any of those examples.

Thank you so much for any help! I'll love you forever if I can get this to work.